# How to change compiler from C to C++ in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: c, eclipse

My project is in C and shared library in C++ (I using Eclipse IDE on Linux platform). Default setting of project taking C compiler (GCC). Can anybody suggest me how to change compiler from C to C++ for my project.

Comment: What is the extension of your source files? `*.c` or `*.cpp`

Comment: I would suppose saving your files with "C++ extension" like cpp or cc or cxx would have the intended effect, but this is not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

GCC can compile both C and C++ source files. It uses filename extensions to determine if it should compile as C or C++.

[C++ source files conventionally use one of the suffixes ‘.C’, ‘.cc’, ‘.cpp’, ‘.CPP’, ‘.c++’, ‘.cp’, or ‘.cxx’; C++ header files often use ‘.hh’, ‘.hpp’, ‘.H’, or (for shared template code) ‘.tcc’; and preprocessed C++ files use the suffix ‘.ii’. GCC recognizes files with these names and compiles them as C++ programs even if you call the compiler the same way as for compiling C programs (usually with the name gcc).](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b)

Answer (score 0):

GCC: GNU Compiler Collection

gcc: GNU C Compiler g++: GNU C++ Compiler

The main differences:

```
gcc will compile: .c/.cpp files as C and C++ respectively.

g++ will compile: .c/.cpp files but they will all be treated as C++ files.

Also if you use g++ to link the object files it automatically links in the std C++ libraries (gcc does not do this).
```